# Props might be undefined

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have a small Vue functional component that gets a prop from it's parent:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExpandedMovieInformation',
  props: {
    movie: {
      type: Object as PropType<Movie>,
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const { movie } = props;
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div class='overlay'>
      <h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
      <span class='release-date'>{{ movie.release_date }}</span>
      <p>{{ movie.overview }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Initiating the component in the parent:

```
<ExpandedMovieInformation
  :movie="currentMovie" />
```

The code compiles but in the template I get warnings that:

[image]

How do I correctly assign a type to a prop so it's not possibly undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you give the movie parameter when making a ExpandedMovieInformation list component like this:

```html
<ExpandedMovieInformation :move="currentMovie" />
```

does not mean that everyone will do that, someone might make the component without that property:

```html
<ExpandedMovieInformation />
```

Therefore the property might be undefined.
To fix this issue you might want to add a default value for the property which is done like this:

```js
props: {
    movie: {
      type: Object as PropType<Movie>,
      default: {}
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the default property. But now of course I get the message that certain properties such as `overview` are not available on type `{}` so the only way to get around this issue is to create a empty Movie object as default. Kinda strange.

Comment: no problem, about the non available properties: thats the most intuitive way to do it i guess, i would do the same